# Match user name and password with mysql and php not working

Tags: php, mysql

I design a log in page and i want to match the username and password with saved data from database and open the dashboard page here is my html code.

```
> <form class="m-t" role="form" method="post" action="dashboard_4.html">
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required=""
> name="logemail">
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="form-group">
>                     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required=""
> name="logpass">
>                 </div>
>                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" id="login" name ="submit">Login</button>
> 
>                 <a href="login.html#"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
>                 <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
>                 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="register.html">Create an account</a>
>             </form>
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sehnoqta_userbmc";
$password = "u?gQ=uS%t;a?";
$dbname = "sehnoqta_bmc";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = $_POST['logemail'];
$password = $_POST['logpass'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sehnoqta_userbmc","?gQ=uS%t;a?","rsehnoqta_bmc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$qz = "SELECT * FROM regis where email1='".$username."' and password3='".$password."'" ; 
$qz = str_replace("\'","",$qz); 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qz);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row == 1)
  {
  header("location:new_page.php");
exit();
  }
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

but it open the page even i type the username and password incorrect, is there any problem with my code or any....

Comment: you're using the same variables for both your db connection and the query.

Comment: and the form's action's file extension is incorrect. It should be a `.php` file, not `.html` unless you instructed your system to treat html files as php.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you show me please : )

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Whatever is `$qz = str_replace("\'","",$qz); ` supposed to do? It looks like it destroys your query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using different variables to your connection. Use same username and passwords, otherwise you will have access denied. I just removed your css and simplified few things. (note: this is a solution for the mentioned question with its code provided. It is not a solution for data expose and security reasons)

File: login.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LogIn.php</title>
</head>
<body align="center">

 <form name="form" method="post" action="dashboard_4.php">
    <div >
        <input type="email" placeholder="Username" name="logemail">
    </div>

    <div >
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="logpass">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="login" name ="submit">Login</button>

    <a ><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
    <p ><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
    <a >Create an account</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

File dashboard_4.php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sehnoqta_userbmc";
    $password = "u?gQ=uS%t;a?";
    $dbname = "sehnoqta_bmc";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","sehnoqta_userbmc","u?gQ=uS%t;a?","sehnoqta_bmc");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['logemail'];
        $password = $_POST['logpass'];

        $qz = "SELECT * FROM regis WHERE email1='$username' and password3='$password' ";
        //echo $qz."<br/>";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$qz);

        //$temp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        //echo $temp['email1']." ".$temp['password3'];;

        $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($row == 1){
            header("location:new_page.php");
            exit();
        }//else {echo "no record combination";}
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

why dont you try:

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sehnoqta_userbmc";
$password = "u?gQ=uS%t;a?";
$dbname = "sehnoqta_bmc";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['logemail']);
$password = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['logpass']);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sehnoqta_userbmc","?gQ=uS%t;a?","rsehnoqta_bmc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con , $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con , $password);
$qz = "SELECT * FROM `regis` where `email1` = '$username' and `password3` ='$password'" ; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$qz);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row == 1)
  {
  header("location:new_page.php");
exit();
  }
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried but it do the same it open the dashboard even i enter incorrect username and password

Comment: i tried but it do the same like sql command has no effect. it open the dashboard even i enter wrong username and password

Comment: what difference would it possibly make adding ticks? I'll tell you: none. You also missed some important tidbits.